# R showing error - "Building a Basic Calculator"

Tags: r

```
add <- function(x, y) {
  return(x + y)
}
subtract <- function(x, y) {
  return(x - y)
}
multiply <- function(x, y) {
  return(x * y)
}
divide <- function(x, y) {
  return(x / y)
}

factors <- function(x) {
  if (choice == 5 | choice == 6) {
    choice <- readline(prompt = "Enter the number: ")
  }
  
  else {
    num1 = as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter first number: "))
    num2 = as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter second number: "))
  }
}


# take input from the user
print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")
print("5. Factors")
print("6. Prime")

choice = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter choice[1/2/3/4/5/6]: "))
num1 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter first number: "))
num2 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter second number: "))
operator <- switch(choice,"+","-","*","/")
result <- switch(choice, add(num1, num2), subtract(num1, num2), multiply(num1, num2), divide(num1, num2), factor(i)
print(paste(num1, operator, num2, "=", result))



ERROR IN R CONSOLE -


> choice = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter choice[1/2/3/45/6]: "))
Enter choice[1/2/3/45/6]: num1 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter first number: "))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> num2 = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter second number: "))
Enter second number: operator <- switch(choice,"+","-","*","/")
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> result <- switch(choice, add(num1, num2), subtract(num1, num2), multiply(num1, num2), divide(num1, num2))
> print(paste(num1, operator, num2, "=", result))
Error in paste(num1, operator, num2, "=", result) : 
  object 'num1' not found
```

This is the error thats generated by R.It appears that R is not able to run through the integers as per my commands. I cannot understand whats wrong with it. I have made few changed but even then the errors appear to be the same. When i run the code until the inputs taken from the user it runs quite fine but the inputs are not recognizing num1 and num2 it says -
"Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion"
I do not understand since I'm a beginner. Please help me out.
Thank you

Comment: The code works fine if you run it line by line but I am guessing you are running all the lines together.

Comment: Yes, it does run until im taking inputs from the user.
But it does not work from 

choice <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter choice[1/2/3/4/5/6]: "))
num1 <- as.double(readline(prompt="Enter first number: "))
num2 <- as.double(readline(prompt="Enter second number: "))
operator <- switch(choice, "+", "-", "*", "/")
result <- switch(choice, add(num1, num2), subtract(num1, num2), multiply(num1, num2), divide(num1, num2), factor(i))
print(paste(num1, operator, num2, "=", result))